# Только что загруженное изображение отобразить в этом же представлении

Tags: c#, ajax, файлы, mvc

Добрый день/вечер, товарищи!
Необходимо СРАЗУ после загрузки изображения...

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="file" name="uploadImage" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

...показать его в этом же представлении.

**Как написать такой скрипт?)**

Comment: Загружается файл посредством submit'а формы или ajax'ом?

Comment: submit формы. Но хотелось бы после указания на файл, оно закрыло всплывающее окно с выбором файла(и так закроет) - но и сразу отобразит изображение.

Comment: используйте [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)